I want to connect to a database in Visual Studio using MySql.Data
I try to connect to a database using MySql.Data but it doesn't work. What did i do wrong?
                private List<Car> cars;
        private MySqlConnection conn;
        private static uint DB_PORT = 3306;
        private static string DB_HOST="localhost";
        private static string DB_USER = "root";
        private static string DB_PASSWORD = "";
        private static string DB_DATABASE = "database";

        public ...()
        {
            cars = GetCars();
                }

public List<Car> GetCars()
        {
            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.Password = DB_PASSWORD;
            builder.Port = DB_PORT;
            builder.Database = DB_DATABASE;
            builder.UserID = DB_USER;
            builder.Server= DB_HOST;
            conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
            MySqlCommand cmd=new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32("id");
                string license_plate_number = reader.GetString("license_plate_number");
                string brand = reader.GetString("brand");
                string model=reader.GetString("model");
                int daily_cost = reader.GetInt32("daily_cost");

                Car car=new Car(id, license_plate_number, brand, model,daily_cost);
                cars.Add(car);
            }

            return cars;
        }

It doesn't send any error codes, but it doesn't connect to the database succesfully because the list has no elements.

In your select statement, can you try specifying the column names this way:  select id, license_plate_number, brand, model, daily_cost from cars?
